# How to create curved cutout in css

Tags: css

I am attempting to create the following bottom navigation:

[image]

You can see how the middle is cutout around the sell button.

I have gotten it this far:

[image]

I have not tried much because I don't know where to begin to make a bowl shape at the bottom of the gap.

I added. a div to the bottom of the gap with the following styles:

```
  .sell-wrapper {
    height: 3.2rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;

    .sell-bottom {
      height: 1.6rem;
      width: 4rem;
      background-color: map-get($map: $colors, $key: foreground);
    }
  }
```

It then looks like this:

[image]

What styles can I apply to the div in the center to get that smooth bowl shape?

Thanks in advance for your help!

```css
.sell-wrapper {
    height: 3.2rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;

    .sell-bottom {
      height: 1.6rem;
      width: 4rem;
      background-color: map-get($map: $colors, $key: foreground);
    }
  }
```

```html
<div> I lost my HTML, please help </div>
```

Comment: Please add the HTML you have tried also

Comment: I created a snippet where you can place the HTML

Comment: Also, I simply coped your CSS including the syntax error